# Visual Code Studio and Github: my new branch not taking into account my change

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new with Visual Studio Code and Github.
I've managed to get a remote project by using Git plugin on Visual Studio Code by doing this:

```
git clone master
```

I was on the master branch and made some changes.
After a while I realised that it would be a better idea to work on another branch.

I did:

```
git create branch mynew_branch
```

and then made a commit.

Now I've checked but both branches are exactly the same ie the way it was at the beginning and none of my changes is on git.
What have I done wrong ?

Comment: Did you do a git push after that?

Comment: Did you type *litterally* `git create branch my new_branch`? If so, there are at least two problems... (get rid of `create` and avoid whitespace in your branch name)

Comment: no that was a mistake when writting my question. I edited it.

Comment: @praneet yes I did. I did another one and it told me everything was up to date. but my local branch is different from the remote one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I though that one button of Visual Studio Code was committing, but it wasn't.

So I used the terminal to make my commit and my push and it worked fine.